# How do I build a path containing variables?

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to create a file into a directory, but the path contains two variables and I get error.

```
TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(variable1+ "\" + variable2 + ".txt", true);
tw.WriteLine(textbox.Text);
tw.Close();
```

Which is the correct format of a path in StreamWriter?

Comment: In future, please specify *what error you received* rather than just indicating that there *was* an error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well you'll have got an error because `"\"` isn't a valid string literal.

However, you'd be better off using [`Path.Combine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine.aspx) - and also [`File.AppendAllText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.appendalltext.aspx):

```
var file = Path.Combine(variable1, variable2 + ".txt");
File.AppendAllText(file, textBox.Text);
```

Note that if you *did* still want to use a writer, you should use a `using` statement so the file handle is closed even if an exception is thrown.

Comment: I get error "The given path's format is not supported." in File.AppendAlltet command, while the file isn't created. I don't know if I made it clear, but I want to save variable2.txt into directory variable1.

Comment: @D-Lef: Well that's what the code I've given will do - but only if the values of `variable1` and `variable2` are appropriate. What *are* the values of those variables?

Comment: Yes, you are right, the value of variable2 was not appropriate. It is equal to the ShortTimeString of a datetimepicker and it includes space, like "12:43 a.m.". I 'll have to think some other way to use it. Thanks for your time!

Comment: @D-Lef: Why not just format the time with a custom format, e.g. `HHmmss` using the invariant culture?

Comment: I tried it, but again something I 'm doing wrong. The command 
string var = start_picker.ToString("HH.mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); gives error "No overload for method ToString takes 2 arguments"

Comment: @D-Lef: You probably want something like `start_picker.Value.ToString(...)`. You're not converting the time picker itself - you're converting its value.

Answer (score 3):

You need to escape the `\` characters.

Either of these will work:

```
TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(variable1+ "\\" + variable2 + ".txt", true);
```

or

```
TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(variable1+ @"\" + variable2 + ".txt", true);
```

However, it's generally considered better to use `Path.Combine` to build paths.

Answer (score 0):

`\` is an *escape character*.

You need to use a verbatim string literal, which doesn't use escape characters:

```
@"\"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(variable1+ "\\" + variable2 + ".txt", true);
```

Doing backslash quotation mark is a way of literally writing a quotation mark in a string, so you need to do a double backslash in order to write a single backslash.